# Изменение массива между прерываниями

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

У меня есть программа на C общения с устройством по UART.
У меня есть массив dataArr, в котором хранятся числа и со временем они будут обновляться в функции main.
Иногда вызывается прерывание при получении информации HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback и там ответом отправляется массив dataArr.
Как правильно это реализовать? Ведь может возникнуть ситуация, когда во время обновления массива вызовется прерывание и будут отправлены неверные данные.

Comment: я бы использовал freertos, из callback передаёте данные в очередь, а в программе (или в каком-то task) забираете из очереди

Answer (score 1):

На время обработки массива запретите прерывания. Я погуглил, у вас в IDE должны быть функции `__enable_irq()` и `__disable_irq()`.

[Пример использования](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0491/i/Compiler-specific-Features/--disable-irq-intrinsic) в документации на компилятор ARM:

```
void foo(void) {
    int was_masked = __disable_irq();
    /* здесь вы обновляете dataArr */
    if (!was_masked) {
        __enable_irq();
    }
}
```